# How to write condition for below in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
create table test (custID varchar(20), currNo int)
insert into test 
values ('00123', 1) ,('00123', 2), ('00123', 3),
        ('00124', 2), ('00124', 3),
        ('00125', 3),('00125', 4),
        ('00126', 1),('00126', 3)
```

I need to select only those custID which has currNo != 1 but it can have currNo > 1

And below is my piece of my code;

```
select distinct custID from test
where currNo != 1 and currNo > 1
```

Result for above query :

```
00123
00124
00125
00126
```

Excepted Result :

```
00124
00125
```

Please correct my query to get desired output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expected result also has 1 in it and is also greater than 1. So what exactly you want to do here?

Comment: 00123 ,00126 both contain value currNo>1 so it came on your result set

Comment: yes  but 123 and 126 also have currNo =1 so i need not want that. i need only custId not as 1 but it can have >1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use simple `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` conditions applied on `currNo`

```
SELECT custID FROM #test
GROUP BY custID
HAVING MIN(currNo)<>1
```

Result

```
custID
00124
00125
```

Comment: Quick performance test shows this as quickest too, especially if there is an index on  (custid,currno). Suprised me actually.

Comment: Yes. I too tested execution cost of all answers, this one seems good without indices. However Distinct will cost much some time. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct contractid from test
where not exists(select * from test t2 where t2.contractid=test.contractid and t2.currNo=1)
```

Comment: By the way - is it contractID or custID? Your table says custID and your query contractID.

Comment: sorry its a Typo, i changed it now.And thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

using not in

```
  select distinct custID from test
where custID not in (select custID from test t2 where t2.custID=test.custID and t2.currNo=1)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ee7c0e/10

```
custID
00124
00125
```

Answer (score 1):

another way of doing it using `LEFT JOIN`

```
select distinct t1.custID 
from test t1
left join test t2 on t1.custid=t2.custid and t2.currno=1
where t2.custid is  null
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/QKFOP81387)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT custID FROM #test
GROUP BY custID
HAVING MIN(currNo)<>1 AND COUNT(currNo) > 1